# 自社製品に関するQ&Aを投稿してもよい？

Tags: 討議, 質問の仕方

- [Visual Studio Community 2013 のインストールイメージをダウンロードするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1540/8000)
- [PayPalのAPI情報（APIユーザー名、APIパスワード、API署名）の取得方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/25026/8000)
  （および同ユーザーによる多数の投稿）

にスパムとして通報を受けました。スパム通報の説明文を引用すると、次のような投稿です。

> 製品やサービスの広告のために使われていて、自分が関係者であることも隠しています。

関連 [スパム発信者にならないようにどうすればいいですか？ - ヘルプ センター](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

回答の中で自らの製品に触れる場合は、自分が関係者であることを明記し、きちんとした回答をするように、というのが上記ヘルプセンターに書かれているかと思います。が、今回の場合はその製品に関する質問ですから、回答だけ見れば広告というほどではないでしょう。

このような投稿はスパムだと思いますか？あるいは普通に質問・回答として評価して、必要ならクローズする、というだけでよいでしょうか？

Comment: 関連記事：http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/product-support

Comment: ヘルプの`「このエラーの原因は何でしょうか？」はStack Overflowに投稿してください`、が、文面通りに受け取ると質問の例の使い方を許容している感じに受け取れます。、ただマイナス票からすると受け入れられてはいないようですが……。

Comment: 自社ソフトのQAを投稿している方の質問ですが承認されているものがないように思えます。2日以内のものは仕方ないとしても、承認されない解決済みの質問があるのはどうかな？とも考えます。

Answer (score 11):

### 広報を目的とした投稿一般

投稿の動機が自社の広報であるか否かは、問われるべきでないと思います。
結果として、良質のQ&Aが残るのであれば構わない筈です。

しかし、回答をしてくれるのでなく、質問から作ってしまわれる方の場合、以下の問題が考えられます。

1. だれも疑問に思っていない質問になり、ノイズにしかならない
2. 回答があるにもかかわらず、露出を増やす動機があり、回答が必要な他の質問が（表示順位の低下などで）排除される
3. 自社で抱えている大量のリソースを一挙に投入するので、StackOverflowの質問フォーマット、フローにマッチしない

StackOverflowには、投稿に対する評価により、一定の基準でIDがロックされる仕組みなどもあるようです。
一律に広報を禁じなくとも、上記のような問題のある質問に個別にマイナス票やクローズで対応していけば大丈夫なのではないかと期待します。

### 今回の通報対象に関して

MSの方は「どこでダウンロード出来ますか？」という、ひどいというか、微笑ましいといいますか上記1.の「だれも疑問に思っていない質問」にあたるかと思います。
ただ、まれにこういった事も分からない事が実際にありますので、クローズまでするかというと……私はマイナス票で十分です。

PayPalの方は質問は一見まともなのですが、以前[承認するようコメントした](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/25033/paypal%e3%81%aeapi%e3%82%a8%e3%83%a9%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b3%e3%83%bc%e3%83%8910002security-header-is-not-valid#comment26114_25033)際も反応がありません。
多方面にマルチポストしているようでもあり、機械化された行動しか取れない様子です。
上記3.の「StackOverflowの質問フォーマット、フローにマッチしない」に当たるかと思います。
このままではマイナス票を投じ Community♦ による回転を止めるしか無く、Q&Aとしてはまともそう（私には評価できませんが）なのに残念ではあります。
["Stack Overflow Documentation"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation)の日本語版が出来れば、そちらにお願いしたい内容ですね。

---

追記:
どうやら、PayPalの方のように連続して投稿なさる方には、マイナス評価で対応するのは難しいようです。
Myakuさんによれば、評価を付けた側のアカウントがロックされる事もあるようですし、そもそも連続した評価はシステムによって取り消されるようです。

そもそも、この方に関してはPayPalの社員かも分からず、「自社製品に関するQ&Aの投稿」というくくりでは対応出来ない気がします。
決済システムに関わる事でもあり、個人的には不気味さを感じつつあります。

Comment: 連投されている方の質問全てにマイナス票を行っていくと一定数で此方側のアカウントがロックされたような気がします。票の投票での対策は危険（？）を伴うのでそこは注意点かもしれません。ここでいうIDのロックとはコレ（http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited）のことですかね？

Comment: @Myaku ロックはそれの事だと思います。詳しくは解ってないですが本家で回っているシステムなら期待出来るかな、と思っています。PayPalの人は短かい時間に集中して行動するので、確かに評価での対応が難しいのかも知れませんね。もう一度コメントしてみます。

Comment: 直リンや具体的な操作指示も多く、確かにちょっと怪しく見えますね。そういう意味では関係者であることを自称してもらうより、PayPalの公式サイトを出典として挙げるぐらいしてもらった方がいいのかもしれません。

Answer (score 4):

現在、新着でPaypal関係者であろう方(質問の例にもある方)の連投が著しいです。
jaSOはあまり頻繁に質問が投稿されることはないので、
このようなことをされると他の本当に疑問を持って質問される方の質問が埋もれてしまいます。

すでに回答にあるように、
自社のQ&Aを利用するか、タグwikiを編集するかして、
質問とは別の形態をとるべきかと思います。

勘違いがないように言っておきますと
このような"よくある質問"を共有すること自体は良いことだと私は考えております。
ただ、質問は本当に疑問を持って質問している方に向けてあるべきだと私は思います。

Answer (score 4):

Q&A(FAQ)的な質問・自己回答で承認済みにされていないものについてはCommunityによる上位への表示を意図しているとみなして宣伝・spamと判断してもよいのではと私は思います。

追記:
質問(または回答)に関係者であることの記載は欲しいですが、この記載の有無にかかわらず最低限、 
投稿者のプロフィールに関係者であること（どのような関係なのかがわかるように）が記載されていてほしい。

実際「PP_MTS_Frank」さんの投稿については、宣伝・spamとは思いませんが、以下のような感想しか持ちませんし。

製品・サービスの関係者の投稿っぽい気はするけど、きちんと関係者であることを明示できないような方がそれっぽい投稿をしているなぁ・・・信用していい内容なのかなぁ・・・

Comment: 単に機能を知らないだけで、そのことを伝えれば承認するかもしれませんが、承認済みであれば問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: @unarist 基本的にはOKと思ってます。http://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1540 などはプロモーションぽい気はしますがそういう物については通常運用で通報→判断→結果によりクローズで良いのではと思います。

Comment: 補足しておくと、自己回答は、質問投稿後2日は承認できないので、忘れているだけの人もいるかもしれません。